# Mac unable to set rotations of multiple monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, beta, monitoring, big-sur

Having a little problem with my MacbookPro 2019-15inch-i9 (Big Sur 2020.07.08). I have two vertical monitors(ASUS VG249 1080p 144Hz)(BenQ GW2270 1080p 60Hz) and one normal monitor(DELL 2718Q 4k) set up with it, and they were working fine with a "H-shape" setup.

However I just found after I updated to Big Sur for a week, the setting is failed. I am able to set only 1 monitor rotated. I tried to set the second rotation after the first rotation is successful, but the this operation would reset all the settings of Display, which means the three monitors are all horizontal.

Plus, I've known it can also be a problem to Mac OS 10.15 or 10.14, I've searched it and found these problem unsolved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should expect strange problems with beta software and should not use it on vital equipment that you need to get your work done. You may have just found a bug in Big Sur and should use the bug reporter that Apple places in your dock for these kinds of issues. As for a solving the issue... Perhaps the next beta update will fix the issue. Personally I'd back up my Mac and revert to Catalina.

Comment: Thx a lot. I put up this question because I've known that someone have the same problem remained unsolved, with older Mac OS though.

Comment: This is a bug you should report.  If you know someone with the issue on an earlier version of macOS, you should post the question. However, I can’t replicate the issue as I have 3 monitors total, 2 rotated 90 degrees and both hold the settings.

Comment: Please see [this question and answers](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1714/88313) regarding asking questions about Apple's beta software.  You'll need to [edit] your question to include the relevant info regarding version/build and hardware type.   Also, be sure you've opened a Feedback to Apple about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by making a safe mode reboot.

You need to shut down your MacbookPro, hold command + R. After you get into the safe mode successfully, restart it again.

This time you get into your Mac with a normal mode, and the dual rotation of monitors is working.

A rough assumption is that a safe mode reboot may cleared some cache of the system?

Hope my solution can be helpful to you.

Comment: Don't forget to report it to Apple as part of the beta-testing process.

Comment: @benwiggy Roger